# Best way to add a cross browser hover to a div

Tags: html

How can I add a simple hover to a div that will be compatible with FF, IE7+ and chrome?

All I need is a simple text hover, and I am pretty sure that you can set it as a property of an HTML element but I cant seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to happen...you want some text to appear somewhere when you hover or...?

Comment: What I am looking for is a simple hover, like a tooltip.  It looks like Dave has just posted what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `title` attribute.  This generally renders like a tooltip.

Comment: Doh, ok, this looks like its what I am looking for, 'title' doesnt seem like a very logical attribute name for a hover tho.

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be that if they called it "hover", it might be mistaken for an event instead of a property.